# How to convert parse html with System.Xml.XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I'm trying to parse XML with this C# code;

```
    htmltext = File.ReadAllText("index.html");
    var soup = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    soup.LoadXml(htmltext);
    var items = soup.SelectNodes("//[@class='repo-list-item']");
```

When running the code i get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Xml.XmlException: Expected =, but found > [62]  Line 53, position 91.
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ExpectAfterWhitespace (Char c) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

So I tried adding `Bash("tidy", "-asxhtml -m index.html");` to convert it to xhtml but i get this:

line 88 column 52 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 128 line 88 column 53 - Warning: replacing invalid character code 153 line 121 column 9 - Error:  is not recognized! line 121 column 9 - Warning: discarding unexpected  line 125 column 9 - Error:  is not recognized! line 125 column 9 - Warning: discarding unexpected  line 125 column 126 - Error:  is not recognized! line 125 column 126 - Warning: discarding unexpected  line 125 column 728 - Warning: discarding unexpected  line 131 column 9 - Error:  is not recognized! line 131 column 9
- Warning: discarding unexpected  line 156 column 9 - Warning: discarding unexpected  line 160 column 9 - Warning: missing  before  line 162 column 1 - Warning: inserting implicit  line 166 column 9 - Warning: discarding unexpected  line 170 column 1 - Warning: discarding unexpected  line 188 column 7 - Error:  is not recognized! line 188 column 7 - Warning: discarding unexpected  line 188 column 119 - Error:  is not recognized! 117 warnings, 52 errors were found! Not all warnings/errors were shown.
This document has errors that must be fixed before using HTML Tidy to generate a tidied up version.

...

Installing 3rd-party libraries is currently not an option. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: You need to use HtmlAgilityPack.  Or you could try including the HTML DTD that defines those entities.

Comment: I'm new to installing packages for .net, and I'm not sure exactly what `dotnet` is vs `nuget` and how to install them.
If you'd be able to help me please, I'm running ubuntu (on cloud9), and using mono csharp.

Comment: Can you post the HTML (or some of it) to try and figure out why HTML Tidy fails?